# Download only content not html

Tags: json, vb.net, webclient

On link [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1grin5l7VUa_Yw48H6ScFCKbMWv-Y-QpF)

I have value of JSON like

```
    {  
   "APP_Name":"ThunderStorm",
   "Version":"2.0.0.0",
   "Download_URL":"PathToExe",
   "Release_Info":"Info"
}
```

In my vb.net code when i use link to download that string

```
  Dim client As New Net.WebClient    
     Dim Root_JSON As String = client.DownloadString("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1grin5l7VUa_Yw48H6ScFCKbMWv-Y-QpF")
```

I get bunch of HTML data. I need to download only JSON value so i would be able to deserialize it

```
Dim o_Json As t_Update.JSON_Application = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Application)(Root_JSON)
```

Comment: Side issue, but why have you got a file with an .xml extension which actually contains JSON?

Comment: Anyway the reason you get that is that you are downloading page which is used to view the data, it's wrapped inside the google viewer stuff which you see when you click the link above. What you actually want to use is the download link, which you can discover either by using the Drive API or by watching your browser's network tab when you click the Download button on that page.